# Converting a quintic to Bring-Jerrard form

Tags: polynomials, algebraic-manipulation

[Bring Jerrard Quintic form](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Bring-JerrardQuinticForm.html) is a way to transform a general quintic to the form: $x^5+x+d=0$

A method to do this is laid out in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/542108/how-to-transform-a-general-higher-degree-five-or-higher-equation-to-normal-form?noredirect=1&lq=1) Math.SE post, however, it is pretty tedious. I believe it could be handled better if done by a computer.

I'm not even sure where to start with this one. I have tried many attempts at transforming the math to Mathematica, but all of them have failed. How can I put the quintic in Bring-Jerrard form?

Comment: You've seen [this](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/TechNotes/158/), no?

Answer (score 5):

Coding the [linked post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/542108/how-to-transform-a-general-higher-degree-five-or-higher-equation-to-normal-form?noredirect=1&lq=1) seemed relatively straightforward. I do not believe one can do it for a fully general solution, though (too much time & memory, proabably):

```
Block[{a = 1, b = 2, c = -2, d = 0, e = 1}, 
  res1 = Resultant[poly = x^5 + a x^4 + b x^3 + c x^2 + d x + e, 
    y - (x^2 + m x + n), x]
  ];
elim1 = Solve[Thread[CoefficientList[res1, y][[4 ;; 5]] == 0], {m, n}];

(* principal form *)
princ = res1 /. Last@elim1 // Simplify;
Collect[princ, y]
(*
  1/64 (131631 + 59105 Sqrt[5]) + 1/64 (80330 + 35434 Sqrt[5]) y - 
   3/4 (291 + 125 Sqrt[5]) y^2 + y^5
*)

(* Bring-Jerrard transformation *)
res2 = Resultant[princ, z - (y^4 + p y^3 + q y^2 + r y + s), y];
elim2 = Solve[
   Flatten@{Thread[
      CoefficientList[res2, z][[4 ;; 5]] == 0],
    {5 , 4 p, 3 q}.CoefficientList[princ, y][[1 ;; 3]] == 0},
  {p, q, s}];
elim3 = Solve[CoefficientList[res2, z][[3]] == 0 /. Simplify@Last@elim2, r];
sol = Flatten@{Last@elim2, Simplify@First@elim3};

(* takes a long time to simplify *)
bjform = res2 /. sol // 
    Collect[#, z, Simplify[#, TimeConstraint -> 1] &] &; // AbsoluteTiming
(*
  <time constraint warnings omitted
  {94.3734, Null}  
*)

bjform // N[#, 50] & // Chop[#, 10^-20] &
(*
-5.7647253740168246456506440299463549834109356680148*10^16 - 
 2.0159908782363565552758349179194608052948233385778*10^13 z + z^5
*)
```

It seems to work, which I was interested to find out.  (The numerical coefficients seem hard to evaluate.)